# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in wordpress/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 888

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

I keeping getting tht error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in line 13 " for my code ...its as below
Here is the last part of nav-menu.php code

```
    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/nav-menu.php */
        $menu_item->attr_title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_attr_title', '' );

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/nav-menu.php */
        $menu_item->description = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_description', '' );
        $menu_item->classes = array();
        $menu_item->xfn = '';
    }
} elseif ( isset( $menu_item->taxonomy ) ) {
    $menu_it
```

Comment: What you have posted `$menu_it` next ? and where the if starts ?

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/ohk5wq

Comment: I think you are missing some portion of your code because I don´t see line 13.

Comment: Here is my full file, Please check. https://www.sendspace.com/file/ohk5wq

Comment: what after `} elseif ( isset( $menu_item->taxonomy ) ) {
  $menu_it
` ?

Answer (score -1):

close the curly braces after the elseif block and the error should resolve

and also the curly braces for the function so your end of the script should look like

```
    elseif ( isset( $menu_item->taxonomy ) ) {
        $menu_it;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you closed the function ?? I think it is inside a function  and this is not a solution .

Comment: no!
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in line 889

Comment: `$menu_it` this is incomplete statement .

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoman try now

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu that was a quick solution, till then file was not uploaded by abdullah

Comment: Well that's not my business the question demands to solve the syntax error it does not asks me to update the logic of the code block inside function

Comment: Here is my full file  sendspace.com/file/ohk5wq

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoman the file is corrupted there should have been some more code beneath the statement `elseif ( isset( $menu_item->taxonomy ) ) {$menu_it`